# Active Record - Unknown column for includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm doing an Active Record query like this:

```
esco = EscoContrato.left_joins(
  cliente: {unidade_consumidoras: :usina},
  arrendamento_contratos: { arrendamento_contrato_unidades: { unidade_consumidora: { contas: :fatura_discriminacoes }}}
).where("unidade_consumidoras.distribuidora_id = 4")
```

This works fine, but I would like to use includes, since I'm gonna use these nested tables, so wouldn't do n+1 queries. However, that same query, if I change `left_joins` for `includes`, it gives me the error "unknown column unidade_consumidoras.distribuidora_id". What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `includes` require `references` when using **conditions** to explicitly reference them.

From the [*API*](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes)

> If you want to add conditions to your included models you’ll have to
>   explicitly reference them.

So, this should work

```
EscoContrato.includes(
  cliente: {unidade_consumidoras: :usina},
  arrendamento_contratos: { arrendamento_contrato_unidades: { unidade_consumidora: { contas: :fatura_discriminacoes }}}
  ).where("unidade_consumidoras.distribuidora_id = 4").references(:unidade_consumidoras)
```

Alternatively, you can re-write your query like below without needing `references`

```
EscoContrato.includes(
  cliente: {unidade_consumidoras: :usina},
  arrendamento_contratos: { arrendamento_contrato_unidades: { unidade_consumidora: { contas: :fatura_discriminacoes }}}
  ).where(unidade_consumidoras: {distribuidora_id: 4})
```